# Download Public Github repository using Python function

Tags: python, csv, file, github, repository

I have a CSV file with one column. This column consists of around 100 GitHub public repo addresses (for example, NCIP/c3pr-docs)

I want to know if there is any way to download all these 100 public repo inside my computer using Python.
I don't want to use any command on the terminal, I need a function for it.

I use a very simple code to access to user and repo. Here it is:

```
import csv
import requests
#replace the name with your actual csv file name
file_name = "dataset.csv"
f = open(file_name)
csv_file = csv.reader(f)
second_column = [] #empty list to store second column values
for line in csv_file:
    if line[1] == "Java":
     second_column.append(line[0])
     print(line[0]) #index 1 for second column
```

So by doing this I read a CSV file and get access to the users and repo.
I need a piece of code to help me download all these repo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```py
import requests

def download(user_and_repo, branch):
    URL = f"https://github.com/{user_and_repo}/archive/{branch}.tar.gz"
    response = requests.get(URL)
    open(f"{user_and_repo.split('/')[1]}.tar.gz", "wb").write(response.content)

download("AmazingRise/hugo-theme-diary", "main")
```

Tested under Python 3.9.

Comment: Thank you for your response,  `import csv
import requests
#replace the name with your actual csv file name
file_name = "dataset.csv"
f = open(file_name)
csv_file = csv.reader(f)
second_column = [] #empty list to store second column values
for line in csv_file:
    if line[1] == "Java":
     second_column.append(line[0])
     print(line[0]) #index 1 for second column
`This is my code and I just have user and repo like **NCIP/c3pr-docs** in such case how can I download these repo?

Comment: @ZBokaee I've modified the answer. Just pass that `NCIP/c3pr-docs` into the function `download`.

Comment: Thank you very much. Shouldn't repo in this line `open(f"{repo}.tar.gz", "wb").write(response.content)` be changed to user_and_repo, is so my program shows me this error: _FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'AmazingRise/hugo-theme-diary.tar.gz'_

Comment: do you have any idea about that?